# Error 9 occurring when trying to replicate SUMIF() function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, sumifs

I'm new at VBA and I have to automate a sheet. One of the columns needs to use the equivalent of this SUMIF() function:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$193335, A2,$C$2:$C$193335)
```

Now, suppose I've acquired the amount of rows (r=193335), how can I replicate this formula using VBA, knowing that I don't want to explicitly put `193335` but `r` (because this code is to automate a process and other datasheets might have different amount of rows).

My attempt was the following, through a function:

```
Function Total_Count(rows)
    Dim i As Long
    b = rows - 1
    For i = 1 To b
        Sheets("Data Output").Range("B" & i + 1 & "").Value _
            = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Worksheets _
            ("Data Input").Range("A2:A" & rows & ""), _
            Worksheets("Data Input").Range("A" & i + 1 & ""), _
            Worksheets("Data Input").Range("C2:C" & rows & ""))
    Next i
End Function
```

Notes:

1. I use i+1 as index because I want to start writing the values below the headers.
2. "Data Output" is a sheet I must populate with data from "Data Input"

But I keep getting an error '9' (subscript out of range). I cannot see where the error is and I'd truly like to know if there's a better way to code this.

Comment: Can you give a sample usage? What would a typical value for `rows` be?

Comment: @Comintern something like 263736, more or less.

Comment: The function isn't returning any values

Comment: Why concatenate all the empty strings at the end of ranges? e.g. rows & ""

Comment: @QHarr I want to automate a process. Data will come with different ranges, it is not a fixed amount of rows. So I got the amount of rows first and from that point try to set a range. The approach I tried was concatenating the value of such rows to the end of the range but not sure if that's working or if its causing the issue.

Comment: @ashleedawg I don't even know if its returning a value. All I get is that error.

Comment: I mean I don't think you need to add the "" in this way. And @ashleedawg's comment is that functions return something but you don't have a return statement  of Total_Count = ........ You also don't declare an explicit return type in the function signature e.g. Function Total_Count(rows) As Long

Comment: @QHarr ok... can you tell me how you would do the ranging?

Comment: e.g.   ("Data Input").Range("A2:A" & rows)

Comment: @Qharr  I didn't think the function needed to return since I'm already telling the cells in which I want to present the values. The function is coded to place such values throughout the whole column B of my "Output Data" sheet.

Comment: If you don’t want to return something and simply perform actions then you want a sub not a function

Comment: Not the source of the error here, but `b` is undeclared (and useless). It is a good practice to always declare variable. You can use `Option Explicit` to force variable declaration.